# Joint regression in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to fit a joint regression model in R.  See: Digby 1979, Modified joint regression analysis for incomplete variety x environment data. J. agric Sci, 93, 81-86.

For an experiment measuring yield for a set of plant genotypes gen_i in a collection of environments env_j, the joint regression model is:

yield_ij = env_j + (gen_i):(beta_j) + eps_ij

It seems like the 'gnm' package could fit such a model, but I'm having trouble getting the syntax right.  This is my attempt.

```
library(agridat)
data(digby.jointregression)
dat <- digby.jointregression
require(gnm)
m3 <- gnm(yield ~ gen + Mult(gen,env), data=dat)
coef(m3)
```

From the paper by Digby, the Genotype 'sensitivities' are 
0.953, 0.739, 1.082, 1.025, ...0.947
Presumably these should be obtainable as model coefficients.

Comment: As of 2020, this seems to work now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work now.

```
library(agridat)
data(digby.jointregression)
dat <- digby.jointregression
require(gnm)
m3 <- gnm(yield ~ gen + Mult(gen,env), data=dat)
# In the line below, "-" is just an arbitrary change of sign
# -1.271+.953 is a constant correction to match Digby.
# Results are not exact, but similar to Digby.
as.matrix( -round(coef(m3)[11:20],3)-1.271+.953 )
Mult(., env).genG01 0.953
Mult(., env).genG02 0.668
Mult(., env).genG03 1.125
Mult(., env).genG04 1.048
Mult(., env).genG05 1.205
Mult(., env).genG06 0.852
Mult(., env).genG07 1.134
Mult(., env).genG08 0.901
Mult(., env).genG09 1.278
Mult(., env).genG10 0.946
```